# Compare what lines are missing in two files

Tags: bash, shell

I have two files file1.txt and file2.txt

`cat file1.txt`

home/user/city/a/1.txt
home/user/state/b/2.txt
home/user/county/d/4.txt

`cat file2.txt`

/home/user/city/a/1.txt
/home/user/state/b/2.txt
/home/user/county/c/3.txt

I am trying to figure what *.txt files are missing by comparing both the files and printing the full path of the missing file.

Expected output

/home/user/county/c/3.txt
/home/user/county/d/4.txt

Comment: `comm` is your friend here. See [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) -- there are folks who try to hack this together with `diff`, but it's slower and consumes _far_ more memory, particularly if input size is unbounded.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Is it intentional that the leading slash is missing in file1.txt?

Comment: @Cyrus yes, it is intentional.

Answer (score 2):

`comm -3 <(sed 's/^/\//' file1.txt | sort) <(sort file2.txt) | awk '{print $1$2}'`

Comment: Isn't SO meant to encourage an effort by the poster, not as a Dial-a-Coder-service? Or has that principle been eroded so much that its remnants have been phased out? I missed that memo.

Answer (score 0):

Try `diff`. It tells you that you have a changed line 2 (`2c2`) and gives you the corresponding lines as output.

```
% diff <(sort file1 | sed 's/^/\//') <(sort file2)  
2c2
< /home/user/county/d/4.txt
---
> /home/user/county/c/3.txt
```

(Also consider using `comm` as it's oftentimes already does the job, as pointed out in the other posts)

Comment: `diff` does a lot of work here -- trying to build the shortest possible transform that will make file1 into file2 -- whereas `comm` implements a vastly simpler algorithm and has well-defined boundaries on its possible CPU and memory space. Even though a sorted file is not likely to be able to exercise `diff`'s worst-case behaviors, time and memory behavior is much better-defined with `comm`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess it depends on the use case. Both shine in certain scenarios, and although this is admittedly not the best fit for `diff` I thing it might still be worth knowing it. I'll include a word of caution in the text.

Comment: Isn't SO meant to encourage an effort by the poster, not as a Dial-a-Coder-service? Or has that principle been eroded so much that its remnants have been phased out? I missed that memo.